# How to show only one week at the time using Angular Material Datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, material-design

We are working on integrating the Angular Material Datepicker in our application.

However we would like to be able to show only one week at the time. The current week to be specific.
The user should still be able to reveal the rest of the days of the month by sliding down the calendar.

Here are the images to illustrate what we are aiming for.

Week
[image: Week]
Month
[image: Month]

What would be a good way to accomplish this ?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I am looking for something very similar too