# Is it possible to show only 1 week using PrimeNG calendar?

Tags: angular, calendar, primeng, primeng-calendar

Is it possible to show only one week in the calendar view? Like on the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly2dv.png) (taken from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129931/how-to-show-only-one-week-at-the-time-using-angular-material-datepicker)).

I looked through the attributes of the element and haven't found anything that might change the amount of weeks being represented. Or maybe you have suggestion for another library that can do that? Thank you.

Comment: can you paste your code whatever you tried

Comment: As I have said, I have looked through the attributes of the primeng calendar and haven't actually seen anything that can alter the amount of weeks represented. So I don't have specific code

Comment: It would be possible to have only one week to choose from when using `minDate` and `maxDate`, but not to display just one week.

Answer (score 1):

So, it is actually possible to display only 1 week but only to display. From their [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/calendar), where they explain conditional styling for the specific days:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date10">
    <ng-template pTemplate="date" let-date>
        <span [ngStyle]="{display: (date.day < 21 && date.day > 10) ? 'none' : 'block'}">{{date.day}}</span>
    </ng-template>
</p-calendar>
```

I did not look further into how to switch weeks instead of months from the calendar view because it is simply not worth the effort.